# Forecasting volatility from serially uncorrelated (squared) returns

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autocorrelation, garch, volatility

I am trying to estimate future volatility based on historical stock price data, using (G)ARCH models. I have computed the ACF and PACF of returns and squared returns, and none of them show signs of significant correlation at any lag.

Does that mean that a (G)ARCH model is not applicable here? Is there a different method for forecasting volatility with serially uncorrelated returns and squared returns? Could this apparent lack of serial correlation be an artefact of my chosen sampling frequency (daily)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, uncorrelated squared returns suggest a vanilla GARCH model is not appropriate.

You could try a fancier GARCH model that
a) exploits possible autocorrelations of (absolute value of) returns raised to a power $d\in[1,2)$ (though I would not have high hopes for it given your findings so far),
b) incorporates asymmetry and/or
c) incorporates additional explanatory variables.

Alternatively, you could just use the sample's unconditional variance as the prediction of the future variance.